# Request: A way to support custom button for GSI?

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

I am integrating my app with Google's Identity Service, since the older Google Sign In JavaScript Platform Library is going to be deprecated soon according to this [blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/03/gis-jsweb-authz-migration.html?m=1). But I can't seem to find an actual way to have a custom button unlike in the older SDK.

For example, if I have a button like:

```html
<div class="socialButton" onclick="signInWithGoogle">
  <img class="socialButtonIcon" />
  <span class="socialButtonText"> Sign in with Google </span>
</div>
```

I can't seem to find an API that supports this approach, a way that I tried previously, was to use the [Google 3P Authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference) to get an authorization code, which can be exchanged with JWT token that'll be returned by Google Identity Service. But this requires a server to exchange the code with Google, since it'll be blocked by CORS policy.

I was expecting to have another API from Google that frontend client can call to get the JWT without having to rely on the SDK to render the button. I tried visiting their Github to raise an request, but seems like all of the public repos are for demo purposes. Is there any place where we can request for such functionality to Google to support this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, I would love to add `html` to your code fence. But it has just 4 letters, and to edit a post 6 letters are needed. Why are you using a entire div for a button?

Comment: Hi @KargWare, so sorry for the late response, I added the `html` identifier to the code block. Thanks for the suggestion!
The `div` usage is just an example (but actually the Google button from the SDK is also using a `div` iirc) But anyway, this is more for trying to raise the request to Google whether we can support such flexibility, since I can't find any other place to raise such request.